# How to retrieve the value of a class from stored procedure

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Goal: to use Fluent NHibernate in order retrieve the value of a class into a variable by using a stored procedure.

Problem:

```
using (NHibernate.ISession session = FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec test :@data").SetParameter("data", data).AddEntity(typeof(Test));
}
```

It does not work, what code am I missing in order to retrieve the value of class test in the variable result?

In other words, I would like to retrieve the value that is 1, 2 and asdf in a single class and not list.

I'm using C# code.

Thank you!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @data INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        1 as a,
        2 as b,
        'asdf' c
END
GO
```

C# class:

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual int a { get; set; }
    public virtual int b { get; set; }
    public virtual string c { get; set; }
}

public class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.a);
        Map(x => x.b);
        Map(x => x.c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "does not work". I would assume that you're missing `List<T>()` call at the end of the query.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the value that is 1, 2 and asdf in a single class and not list<T>

Comment: then `UniqueResult()`

Comment: "UniqueResult()" doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.List<T>().Single();
```

You have to retrieve all the data and then retrieve a single data.

Not the recommended solution but it solved the case.